# Error constructing handler for request of type mediatr.irequesthandler`2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, mediatr

This problem occurred when I inject **IMapper** into the MediatR command handler. I injected properly before this happen but after that changed **AutoMapper** and **MediatR** configs like bellow. (I added all assemblies of application layers)

```
services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
                               typeof(CreateAccountCommand).Assembly,
                               typeof(EfRepository<,>).Assembly,
                               typeof(IRepository<,>).Assembly,
                               typeof(KeyValueDto).Assembly);

        services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
                            typeof(CreateAccountCommand).Assembly,
                            typeof(EfRepository<,>).Assembly,
                            typeof(IRepository<,>).Assembly,
                            typeof(KeyValueDto).Assembly);
```

When I execute **CreateAccountCommand** the error occures like bellow:

```
Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.Actions.Users.Commands.CreateAccountCommand,Application.Common.Models.GenericResponse`1[System.String]]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.
```

Inner exception is bellow

```
Property 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Domain.Entities.Thumbnail] Thumbnails' is not defined for type 'Domain.Entities.Thumbnail' (Parameter 'property')
```

Comment: It seems you're running a different version of an assembly than the one you built and tested. You need to get them in sync.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core MediatR error: Register your handlers with the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774060/asp-net-core-mediatr-error-register-your-handlers-with-the-container)

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem, and the solution was to add the following code to my application layer，and then call it from Program

```
public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    return services.AddMediatR(assembly);
}
```

My program code call order

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
builder.Services.AddApplication();
```

Answer (score 0):

builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(MyQuery).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

One way to find out the actual error is to open Event Viewer. In the Event Viewer, go to custom views > Summary Page Events.

Here you can see all the errors which are relevant to your code. In our case, error was coming like this:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
```

Upon checking the error, I was missing appsettings.json in the published folder. Due to the missing appsettings, connection string wasn't found and migration failed with the error:

```
Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler. 
Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples
```