# Use MediatR with Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0, clean-architecture, mediatr

i'm trying to use MediatR in my ASP.NET 6 application, but i need to write `builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(ExampleCommandHandler).Assembly);` for every handler. I was looking for a way to add just in single line like `builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).Assembly);`. But all the examples i saw throw the exception with message `Register your handlers with the container.`

I think this problem is because my Commands and my Command Handlers are in different class library, example of my folder structure:

```
.
└── MyApp/
    └── src/
        ├── MyApp.API/
        │   ├── Startup.cs
        │   └── ...
        ├── MyApp.ClassLibrary1/
        │   ├── Handlers/
        │   │   └── ExampleCommandHandler.cs
        │   └── ...
        └── MyApp.ClassLibrary2/
            ├── Commands/
            │   └── ExampleCommand.cs
            └── ...
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Some of the answers here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774060/asp-net-core-mediatr-error-register-your-handlers-with-the-container

Comment: When you call `.AddMediatR` you can pass multiple assemblies instead of just one, like `builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(ExampleCommandHandler).Assembly, typeof(ExampleCommand).Assembly);`

Comment: @ScottHannen If i use `builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(ExampleCommandHandler).Assembly);` works for every handler, but i don't know why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this problem i've used the following code, just replace `ClassLibrary.Name` with the name of your library:

```
options.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("ClassLibrary.Name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try builder.Services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());